# need to use both @soapaction and @PayloadRoot in single application

Tags: java, xml, spring

We have a spring application in which we have web services which will use both PayloadRoot and SoapAction. Now we have configured the following code in webservice-ws-context.xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping">
        <property name="interceptors">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadLoggingInterceptor"/>
                <bean id="validatingInterceptor"  class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadValidatingInterceptor">
                    <property name="schema" value="classpath:/xsd/common.xsd"/>
                    <property name="validateRequest" value="${uiconnect.ws.payload.validate.request}"/>
                    <property name="validateResponse" value="${uiconnect.ws.payload.validate.response}"/>
                </bean>
            </list>
</property>
</bean>
```

Now, we want to add code for soap action, but if we add the following code then it doesn’t work. So, how we can give the **"id"** attribute to this bean and configure this bin for a particular web service. Or is there any other way to configure this? 
I tried to make custom endpointmapping but help is not available for this.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.mapping.SoapActionAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping">
        <property name="interceptors">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor"/>
                <bean id="validatingInterceptor"  class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadValidatingInterceptor">
                    <property name="schema" value="classpath:/xsd/common.xsd"/>
                    <property name="validateRequest" value="${uiconnect.ws.payload.validate.request}"/>
                    <property name="validateResponse" value="${uiconnect.ws.payload.validate.response}"/>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier way to configure it would be using custom namespace that Spring-WS provides:

First the component scan to ensure that @Endpoint annotated beans are found:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="..." />
```

The following will internally register the `PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping` and `SoapActionAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping`

```
<sws:annotation-driven  />
```

and to register interceptors:

```
<sws:interceptors>
    <bean id="validatingInterceptor"  class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadValidatingInterceptor">
        <property name="schema" value="classpath:/xsd/common.xsd"/>
        <property name="validateRequest" value="${uiconnect.ws.payload.validate.request}"/>
        <property name="validateResponse" value="${uiconnect.ws.payload.validate.response}"/>
    </bean>
    <sws:payloadRoot namespaceUri="....">
        <bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadLoggingInterceptor"/>
    </sws:payloadRoot>
    <sws:soapAction value="...">
        <bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor"/>
    </sws:soapAction>
</sws:interceptors>**
```

Comment: This is working fin thank you very much.This realy helped me a lot.